# Fail if variable does not match a regular expression

Tags: ansible

Looking for an Ansible task that will fail the playbook if a variable does not match a given regex. Something like:

```
# fail when hostname doesn't match a regex
- fail:
    msg: "The inventory hostname must match regex"
  when: {{ inventory_hostname }} not matches [a-z](([-0-9a-z]+)?[0-9a-z])?(\.[a-z0-9](([-0-9a-z]+)?[0-9a-z])?)*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the [assert module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/assert_module.html):

```
- assert:
    that:
    - inventory_hostname is match('your regex')
```

See also [Playbook Tests](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tests.html) and [Filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html)