# Ansible task that verifies complexity of password

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I am trying to take a variable that is saved as a password from an Ansible Tower [Survey](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#surveys) and then verify its complexity.

The password needs to be at least 17 characters and contain uppercase, lowercase, number, and special character.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142164/2123530

Answer (score 0):

Since I have the same use case, to [filter data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) I've started with first with [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) module, Jinja2 filter [`length`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#builtin-filters).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    NEW_PASSWORD: "12345678901234567"

  tasks:

  - name : Check if password is long enough
    assert:
      that:
        - NEW_PASSWORD | length > 16
      success_msg: "Passed."
      fail_msg: "New password is too short!"
      quiet: true
```

It is also possible to use [regex with assert operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400511/) which can be filled within the in the comment mentioned [regex to validate password strength](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142164/6771046).

**Further Q&A**

- [Fail if variable does not match a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753636/6771046)
- [`regex_search` filter comparison and how to debug `when` clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255219/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to generate random string with seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73892680/6771046)