# Ansible: How to generate random string with seed?

Tags: ansible, scripting, ansible-facts, ansible-template, infrastructure-as-code

I know in Ansible we can generate random number with unique seed

```yaml
- name: generate random suffix
  set_fact:
    rand_num: "{{ 1000000 | random(seed=variable_name) | hash('md5') }}"
```

So, if I want to generate a random string with the seed, how can I generate it?

We have Ansible collection available for random string generation - [Random String](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/random_string_lookup.html)

Example:

```yaml
- name: Generate a random string with all lower case characters
  debug:
    var: query('community.general.random_string', upper=false, numbers=false, special=false)
```

But here I couldn't find the option to put seed.

Thanks

Comment: You could have also just rephrased or edited [Ansible code to create a random string with fixed hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876934/) ...

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [`random_string` lookup – Generates random string](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/random_string_lookup.html) and your example

```yaml
upper=false, numbers=false, special=false
```

I understand that you like to generate a random string of length `8` ([since that is the default value of parameter length for module `random_string`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/random_string_lookup.html#parameter-length)) without numbers and special characters and lower case only. In other words, just a short random string with specific properties.

**How to generate an idempotent but random string of length 8 without numbers and special characters and lower case only?**

To do so, one can use the [`password` lookup – retrieve or generate a random ...](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/password_lookup.html) as well. It will only be necessary to define the properties of the result set (`chars=ascii_letters,digit length=8' | lower`).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show string with 8 lowercase characters
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digit length=8') | lower }}"
```

As of Ansible v2.12 a [Parameter: seed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/password_lookup.html#parameter-seed) is available

```yaml
- name: Generate password
  set_fact:
    PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digit length=8', seed=inventory_hostname) | lower }}"
```

to make the result idempotent.

With this approach one'll get a string with the required properties. The `random_string` module support the definition of more or other properties, which you are not using and depend on according your initial description.